# How to read Multiple values in $_POST sent in form data against one parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending form data using ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
             beforeSend: function (request) {
                 request.setRequestHeader("x-ApiKey", "9c8907d4-4425-4118-90ce-93f13af4fdc6");
             },
             type: "POST",
             url: "/apply/crm",
             data: $.param(n),
             success: function(response) {
                 //parent.signin(response);
             },
             error: a
         })
```

data in request is

```
Employment[0].EmploymentStatus: Full-Time Employment
Employment[0].JobTitle.: B1
Employment[0].Employer.: A1
Employment[0].TimeAtEmployerYears: 1
Employment[0].TimeAtEmployerMonths: 1
Employment[1].EmploymentStatus: Full-Time Employment
Employment[1].JobTitle.: B2
Employment[1].Employer.: B2
Employment[1].TimeAtEmployerYears: 2
Employment[1].TimeAtEmployerMonths: 2
```

But it is not found in $_POST, print_r($_POST) showing following output

```
[Employment] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
```

Any help how to read the data submitted in above format

Comment: why some properties end with a dot? e.g. `Employment[0].Employer.`

Comment: Maybe we could if you show us the code that created the POST data. The javascript in other words

Comment: $.ajax({
             beforeSend: function (request) {
                 request.setRequestHeader("x-ApiKey", "9c8907d4-4425-4118-90ce-93f13af4fdc6");
             },
             type: "POST",
             url: "/apply/crm",
             data: $.param(n),
             success: function(response) {
                 //parent.signin(response);
             },
             error: a
         })

Comment: Adding that to your question would make it more readable

Comment: So now ... where does `$.param(n)` get setup to be used in `data: $.param(n),`

Comment: Also, what jQuery version are you using? Since 3.0, the second parameter to `.param` defaults to `false`, whereas you probably want it to be `true` … (can’t say for sure, because we don’t know what data you have in `n` to begin with.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP $_POST does not save data that is being sent as array objects.